# V8 JSON.stringify and wrapped native objects

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I am developing an application which uses the C++ bindings of libv8 (version 3.14) for scripting, and need to serialize data generated by scripts to disk. Currently, I do this via calling V8's builtin `JSON.stringify()` and extracting the resulting JS string. At the same time, I expose (via ObjectTemplate and internal fields) several C++ classes to JS, and it is often meaningful to store them inside JS objects that are to be serialised, e.g.

```
n = getWrappedNativeObject();
to_store = { "a": 1, "b": n };
```

Unfortunately, stringify completely ignores this data, and so any native classes it encounters are translated as `{}`, i.e. `JSON.stringify(to_store) == "{\"a\":1, \"b\":{} }"`.

Is there some way of providing a custom override of how JSON.stringify serialises an object? Barring that, what is the best way to serialise javascript objects that may contain wrapped native objects? (You can assume that the native objects have their own serialisation methods and at the time the JS is to be (de)serialised, I have access to an appropriate mapping between pointers to native objects and IDs which identify them on disk.)

Comment: It has a replacer function that you might be able to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: That's actually pretty nice (and I might be able to hack something nasty that barely works with it), but it would be so much better if I could have similar that allows me to return a bare string to be placed in the JSON: i.e. `JSON.stringify( {magic:1}, function(k,v) { if(k=="magic") return "findNativeObj("+v+")" } )` returning `"{\"magic\":findNativeObj(1)}"` rather than `"{\"magic\":\"findNativeObj(1)\"}"`... (and then I'd use eval instead of JSON.parse to reconstitute it)